# OAuth request to Google succeeds locally, but fails with "invalid_grant" on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, oauth, google-analytics, google-api-client

I'm using a Google service account to make API calls for my [Dashing](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing) dashboard to Analytics. I'm using the Legato gem to get Analytics data, and authenticating using the gem's wiki's [instructions for service accounts](https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/OAuth2-and-Google#service-accounts).

I've put my Google username and private key into ENV (after base 64-encoding it), and am using dotenv to synchronize these settings between local and Heroku (`heroku config` confirms that everything is set correctly). So, my authentication code looks like this:

```
class GoogleAnalyticsAccount
  attr_accessor :user, :profile

  # Thanks to the "Service Accounts" section at
  # https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/OAuth2-and-Google
  def initialize scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
    client = Google::APIClient.new application_name: '[App name]',
                                   application_version: '1.0'

    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(Base64.decode64(ENV['GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64']), "notasecret")

    service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(ENV['GOOGLE_USER'], scope, key)

    client.authorization = service_account.authorize

    oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new("", "", {
       :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
       :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })
    token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth_client, client.authorization.access_token)
    @user = Legato::User.new(token)
  end

  def profile
    @user.profiles.first
  end
end
```

Locally, this code works just fine. On Heroku, I get the following response from Google:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

No more detail than that. Based on extensive Googling, I've found that the two most likely reasons for this are A) I've hit my request limit (but it can't be that, because the same credentials work locally), and B) the server clock isn't synced with NTP. I've set the timezone on Heroku to America/Chicago (same as my local machine), but no dice.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh. I was using dotenv and [heroku-config](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config) to push my settings up to Heroku. Turns out, putting my GOOGLE_USER and GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64 inside quote marks in my `.env` file was taken literally by heroku-config, and it was pushing those settings *with quote marks* to my Heroku config. Thus, the username/key were invalid—hence `invalid_grant`.

And to think I've been working on this problem for days...